# Interesting mysql query

Tags: join, aggregate-functions, mysql-5.7

I have 2 different tables.

My goal is to find people who use the same ip address with different names.

Table 1 - logs

Fields: member_id, ip_adress

Table 2 - members

Fields: id, name, last_name

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Are you having issues inserting the data? Please add code that shows your issue.

Comment: @user3783243 My question is clear. I have two tables as logs and members.

My goal is to find people whose name and surname are not the same but use the same ip address.

I would like help with this query.

Comment: So is there an issue with PHP, or this is just a mysql question? Do you have example queries you've tried?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Dekel I think I asked my question correctly.

Comment: Read your post. There is no question. Also no research effort. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify which IP addresses have multiple members.

For example:

```
select id, name, last_name
from (
  select m.*,
    row_number() over(partition by l.ip_address 
                      order by m.name, m.last_name) as rn 
  from members m
  join logs l on l.member_id = m.id 
) x
where rn = 2
```

**EDIT FOR MYSQL 5.7**

Since MySQL 5.x doesn't have window functions, you can do:

```
select m.*
from members m
join logs l on l.member_id = m.id
where l.ip_address in (
  select l.ip_address
  from members m
  join logs l on l.member_id = m.id
  group by l.ip_address
  having min(m.name) <> max(m.name) or min(m.last_name) <> max(m.last_name)
)
```

See [Running Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rGu5wxAhGQ5j8Z3YdoZ3Hi/0) at DB Fiddle.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by l.ip_address
                      order by m.name, m.last_name)' at line 4

Comment: You didn't specify the version of MySQL. Seems that yours is old.

Comment: 5.7.29 - MySQL Community Server (GPL). Doesn't it have a different solution?

Comment: I updated the tags of your question, so other people may answer right.

Comment: Hey The Impaler

I have 2 different tables.

My goal is to find people who use the same ip address with different (name and surname).

Table 2 - members

Fields: id, name, surname

87 - john - but 88 - john - but 89 - alex - lopez 90 - david - beckham Table 1 - logs

Fields: member_id, ip_adress

87 - 1.1.1.1 88 - 1.1.1.1 89 - 2.2.2.2 90 - 2.2.2.2

The result I want to get

2.2.2.2 - 89,90 - total (2 )

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61283178/mysql-two-different-tables-group-by

Comment: @perfectmorn gimme a min. lemme try again.

Comment: @perfectmorn There ya go. Mind that I made the extra effort cause the coronavirus has me trapped here inside on a friday night. Sigh.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

I'm sorry for you.

Comment: @perfectmorn The second query runs in MySQL 5.7. See the running example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rGu5wxAhGQ5j8Z3YdoZ3Hi/0 It has all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Last question, can we act according to the last 1 month in the log table?

I have datetime format field  -> name = last_time

Also would you suggest for huge data?

Also this query works but did not give me what I wanted?

Comment: The query is correct, thanks. All I want is can we do it according to the data in the last 1 month in the log table?

Comment: For the last month of data you can just add an extra condition in the `WHERE` clause. For huge data, please ask another question.

Comment: This correct ? join logsl on l.member_id= m.id
where l.last_time>= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY and l.ip_adress in (....

Comment: I tried very hard, but the query runs very slowly. There are more than 1 million data in the log table.

Also, are you sure that this query detects 2 different "name surname" entries from an ip address?

Comment: The query is probably wrong.
There are about 28,000 members.

However, 439,395 records are shown as a result of the query :)  @The Impaler

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT for that:

```
SELECT
    ip_adress, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2 ON table1.member_id = table2.id
GROUP BY
    ip_adress
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Thanks, but I can do that too. My goal is to find people who have different name and surnames but use the same IP address.